# mintinline in footnote doesn't resize properly

Tags: footnotes, minted

When setting up the `minted` environment to use a specific fontsize, it is not correctly resize with the environment.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\setminted[c++]{fontsize=\footnotesize}
%% define shortcut
\newcommand{\cd}[1]{\mintinline{c++}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cdfoot}[1]{\mintinline[fontsize=\scriptsize]{c++}{#1}}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

regular inline \cd{code}\footnote{footnote \cd{code} (the same size as in text)}

regular inline \cd{code} {\footnotesize \cd{code}} (no difference)

regular inline \cd{code} \cdfoot{code} (this would be expected)

\end{document}
```

As shown, I can work around the problem by using an extra command, but this is error-prone since the visual difference is rather small and it is easy miss incorrect usage.

Comment: Make a complete example that can be used for tests. And if possible use a font that is available on all tex systems.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, I am reducing this to MWE that in part will have separate questions. I will return to this later or close this.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want that `\cd` uses a context depending font size, namely `\footnotesize` in normal size and `\scriptsize` in footnotes (or when `\footnotesize` is in force).

You're lucky, because `scrbook` uses 9pt size for `\footnotesize`, so you can easily use `relsize`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{scrhack}

%% define shortcut
\newcommand{\cd}{\mintinline[fontsize={\smaller}]{c++}}

\textheight=6cm % just to get a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

regular inline \cd{code}\footnote{footnote \cd{code} (the same size as in text)}

regular inline \cd{code} {\footnotesize footnotesize \cd{code}}

\end{document}
```

[image]